# Что делать со statment, когда выпадет исключение при его закрытии в Java?

Tags: java, исключения, jdbc, обработка-ошибок

Знакомые рассказывали, что на приемке проекта у них в команде проверяющий указывал им на явное закрытие объекта `Statement`. Я тоже задался таким вопросом и пошёл смотреть, что по этому поводу говорит [официальная документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close--):

> It is generally good practice to release resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up database resources.

Следовательно, хорошей практикой является **явное** закрытие `Statement`, делается это, судя по всем, таким образом:

```
try {
        // работа со statemen'ом
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to execute SQL statement: {}.", SQL_PROCEDURE_CREATE_ACCOUNT);
        throw new DaoException("Failed to execute SQL statement: " + SQL_PROCEDURE_CREATE_ACCOUNT, e);
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //todo а если не удалось закрыть statement, что тогда делать?

            LOGGER.error("Database access error occurs when trying to close Statement object.", e);
            throw new DaoException("Database access error occurs when trying to close Statement object." + e);
        }
    }
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Что делать с объектом `statment`, если при попытке его закрытия с помощью явного вызова метода `statement.close()` выпадает исключение `SQLException`, которое, согласно, официальной документации, может выброситься в следующей ситуации:

> Throws: SQLException - if a database access error occurs

2. Нужно ли всё таки явно закрывать `statement` вызовом метода `statement.close()`, если сам объект `Statement` реализует интерфейс `AutoCloseable`?

> Specified by: close in interface AutoCloseable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Закрывать нужно **обязательно**. Как и **любой** объект, который реализует интерфейсы `Closeable`/`AutoCloseable`
2. Причем лучше всего это делать при помощи оператора [try-with-resorces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

   ```java
   try (Statement stmt = ....) {
       // работа со statemen'ом
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       LOGGER.error("Failed to execute SQL statement: {}.", SQL_PROCEDURE_CREATE_ACCOUNT);
       throw new DaoException("Failed to execute SQL statement: " + SQL_PROCEDURE_CREATE_ACCOUNT, e);
   }
   ```
3. С исключением, которое может возникнуть при закрытии работать как и с любым другим: если можем - обрабатываем, если нет - выпускаем дальше

Вот типичный код для работы с базой данных

```java
try (Connection con = .......) {
  ......
  try (Statement stmt = con.PrepareStatement(...)) {
    ......
    try (ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery()) {
      .........
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: То, что закрывать надо - это понятно, правда вопрос в другом - следует ли это делать явно или неявно (как в вашем коде)?

Comment: @RomanC Это не играет никакой роли. С оператором `try-with-resorces` получается меньше кода и он автоматически вставляет `finally` блоки. Вы ходили по ссылке, читали описание оператора?

Comment: Как это не играет? Ещё очень играет, вы уклонильсь от ответа, пытаясь навязать ОП свою точку зрения. И поскольку вы не хотите отвечать на мой вопрос в предыдущем комменте, то общение с вами бесполезно.

Comment: @RomanC Я ответил на ваш вопрос. Разницы между `obj = ...; try {...} finally {obj.close()}` и `try (obj = ...) { ... }` нет

Comment: Ещё раз: нужно ли это делать явно или неявно - вот в чем вопрос. Разница есть, если вы ее не видите, то опять, я вас прошу: мне не надо тут доказывать, пишите для людей, разжевывыйте им свое мнение. Мне это не интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Сами ответили на свой вопрос

> Следовательно, хорошей практикой является явное закрытие `Statement`

Правда тут надо добавить, что если выполняется неявное закрытие, т.е. если используется try with resources, то исключение, возникающее при выполнении `close()` следует отлавливать отдельно.

Интерфейс `AutoClosable` не закрывает Statement автоматически, а служит для неявного закрытия, как например в ситуации, упомянутой выше.

И теперь

> //todo а если не удалось закрыть statement, что тогда делать?

Ну тут причины могут быть разные, но в большинстве случаев толку от этого мало, поэтому исключение можно просто игнорировать.

Comment: `Ну тут причины могут быть разные, но в большинстве случаев толку от этого мало, поэтому исключение можно просто игнорировать.` А зачем его тогда вообще обрабатывать, если его можно проигнорировать? Тогда лучше вообще не обрабатывать.

Comment: Обрабатывать нужно, чтобы проигнорировать. Потом, это исключение является checked, поэтому требуется его отлавливать.