# Как правильно инициализировать и закрывать Statement?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Есть класс (`SQLExecClass`) который работает с БД в рамках прогона теста(-ов), в нём
метод (`void execSQL(String sql)`) который принимает на вход SQL строку, в конструктор класса передаётся объект класса-подключения к БД (`DBConnector`). В методе создаю Statement: `Statement statement = DBConnector.getConnection().createStatement()`. Нашёл в такую инфу:

> Объекты Statement закрываются автоматически сборщиком мусора виртуальной машины Java. Тем не менее рекомендуется закрывать их явно после того, как работа с ними завершена

Я в классе теста создаю объект `SQLExecClass` и использую его за тест 5-15 раз. В связи с чем вопрос в каком месте лучше инициализировать `Statement`? В конструкторе класса или в методе? Когда стоит его закрывать в конце теста (если в конце теста, то надо сделать метод для закрытия в `SQLExecClass`?) или в методе после выполнения запроса, и стоит ли вообще его самому закрывать?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302010/204920) можете почитать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Воспользовался ответом [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301808/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE-statment-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java/1302010#1302010) - использовал  конструкцию `try-with-resources`:

```
try (Connection con = .......) {
  ......
  try (Statement stmt = con.PrepareStatement(...)) {
    ......
    try (ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery()) {
      .........
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменную надо использовать максимально близко к месту использования, это не касается статических переменных. Закрывая statment вы указываете gc на просьбу освободить память от объект на который не существует ссылки