# Получение всех User из базы и вывод в консоль

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement())
    {
        userList = statement.execute("SELECT * FROM users");
    }
    catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userList;
}
```

**Метод `getConnection()` :**

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection socket = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user1.1.3?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true", "stack", "12345");
    return socket;
}
```

это навоял я, но IntelliJ IDEA со мной не согласна. Подскажите где я ошибаюсь и как правильно.

Comment: `IntelliJ IDEA со мной не согласна` - в чём именно не согласна? Ваш код не компилируется?

Comment: В вопрос нужно включать конкретную ошибку, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1308696/edit) ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так ничего не получится

```
userList = statement.execute("SELECT * FROM users");
```

можно попробовать вот так

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Потом нужно курсором пройтись по всем записям в `rs`. Объекты `User` надо создавать самому, и присваивать полям значения из `rs` и потом добавлять в список. После того как все записи исчерпаны нужно закрыть `rs`. Как это сделать лучше, можно посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302010/204920).