# Ошибка неверного синтаксиса SQL: ...right syntax to use near

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, preparedstatement

Имеется запрос, заданный в таком виде:

```
String GET_BANK_ACCOUNTS_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM bank_account WHERE merchant_id = ?";
```

Соответственно, выполняется запрос так:

```
public static List<BankAccount> getMerchantBankAccounts(String id, Connection connection) throws NoBankAccountsFoundException {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_BANK_ACCOUNTS_QUERY);
            preparedStatement.setString(1,id);
            ResultSet set = preparedStatement.executeQuery(GET_BANK_ACCOUNTS_QUERY);
            List<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while (set.next()) {
                StatusCondition status = (set.getString("status").equals("ACTIVE"))?
                        StatusCondition.ACTIVE: StatusCondition.DELETED;
                list.add(new BankAccount(set.getString("id"), set.getString("merchant_id"),
                        status, set.getString("account_number"),
                        set.getTimestamp("created_at").toLocalDateTime()));
            }
            return list;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new NoBankAccountsFoundException("Таких аккаунтов не найдено, проверьте id мерчанта");
        }
    }
```

При выполнении команды `executeQuery()` выбрасывается исключение

> ...right syntax to use near ?

Данные в БД есть и `id` совпадает с столбцом, по которому и стоит условие `WHERE`. Подскажите, что может быть не так?

Comment: Я, конечно, ни хрена не смыслю в яве... но зачем в executeQuery передавать текст запроса? тем более что он уже вроде как подготовлен...

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос, прикрепив к нему само исключение, так будет быстрее разобраться в чем проблема, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...right syntax to use near ?

MySQL не понимает значения `?` в SQL-запросе.  Это действительно недопустимый синтаксис SQL.  Так что каким-то образом он не был заменен в `PreparedStatement`.

**Вместо:**

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_BANK_ACCOUNTS_QUERY);
preparedStatement.setString(1,id);
ResultSet set = preparedStatement.executeQuery(GET_BANK_ACCOUNTS_QUERY); // Ошибка!!!
```

Вы подменяете один запрос другим запросом!  Вам нужно вызвать метод [`PreparedStatement::executeQuery()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) без аргументов вместо [`Statement::executeQuery(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

**Использовать:**

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_BANK_ACCOUNTS_QUERY);
preparedStatement.setString(1,id);
ResultSet set = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); // Хорошо!!!
```

---

К тому же, в вашем коде происходит утечка ресурсов.  Через некоторое время работы приложения они закончатся, и ваше приложение выйдет из строя.  Чтобы исправить это, вам нужно закрывать ресурсы, когда они больше не нужны. `Connection`, `Statement` и `ResultSet` в блоке `finally` блока `try`, где они были получены или использовать утверждение `try-with-resources` для автоматического закрытия этих ресурсов.  Правда, при этом надо учитывать следующее, которое можно прочитать здесь: [Что делать со statment, когда выпадет исключение при его закрытии в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1302010/204920).

Подробную информацию см. в [руководстве по основам JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html).

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы правы, вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 3):

Как верно указал @Akina в комментарии, для выполнения `PreparedStatement`, возвращающего `ResultSet` следует использовать перегруженный метод без параметров [`PreparedStatement::executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--).

В вашем же случае будет вызываться метод из родительского класса, принимающий сырой текст SQL-запроса [`Statement::executeQuery(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery-java.lang.String-), в котором вместо параметра останется знак вопроса.  Об этом случае специально указано в документации по ссылке:

> `ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) throws SQLException`
> Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single `ResultSet` object.
> *Note:* This method cannot be called on a `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement`.

Также следует использовать `try-with-resources` для корректного закрытия самого запроса и [связанного с ним экземпляра `ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> *A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed when the `Statement` object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.*

Также следует пересмотреть логику обработки `SQLException` и выбрасывания `NoBankAccountsFoundException`, которое должно возникать, если результирующий список пуст.

Исправленный код:

```java
public static List<BankAccount> getMerchantBankAccounts(String id, Connection connection) throws NoBankAccountsFoundException {
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(GET_BANK_ACCOUNTS_QUERY)) {
        preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
        ResultSet set = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        List<BankAccount> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (set.next()) {
            StatusCondition status = (set.getString("status").equals("ACTIVE")) ?
                        StatusCondition.ACTIVE: StatusCondition.DELETED;
            list.add(new BankAccount(
                set.getString("id"), 
                set.getString("merchant_id"),
                status, 
                set.getString("account_number"),
                set.getTimestamp("created_at").toLocalDateTime()
            ));
        }
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoBankAccountsFoundException("Таких аккаунтов не найдено, проверьте id мерчанта")
        }
        return list;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка выполнения запроса: " + GET_BANK_ACCOUNTS_QUERY + "; id=" + id, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо вызывать метод `ResultSet executeQuery() throws SQLException;` из класса `PreparedStatement`, а Вы вызываете метод  `ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) throws SQLException;` из класса `Statement`, который реализуется классом `PreparedStatement`

А проблема заключается в том, что вы уже создали `PreparedStatement` затем передаёте параметры, а потом пытаете выполнить запрос не передав параметры.