# Нет метода setString у PreparedStatement в автодополнении, JDBC mySQL Java 8

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Скачал драйвер JDBC mysql вроде бы последней версии на сайте mysql, закинул в External libraries и все нормально работает.
Но пытаюсь использовать `setString` в `PreparedStatement`, а такого метода нет в автодополнении, когда пишу `setS`, и в предложенных вариантах от ide нет String, и для других методов (`setInt` и т.п.) также автодополнение не работает.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, в том числе, как вы инициализируете драйвер для mySQL.  Класс `java.sql.PreparedStatement` доступен в Java SE, как и весь пакет `java.sql`, см. [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html): `This complete JDBC API is included in the Java SE™`

Comment: У меня java SE 1.8 , есть класс DataBaseConnector там есть метод connectToDataBase , который инициализирует Connection и в конце return connection , в классе в котором я пытаюсь использовать setString , я создаю Statement statement = databaseconnector.connectToDataBase.PreparedStatement(sql); потом в sql пытаюсь изменить на нужные данные , но setString нету

Comment: Всё верно, в вашем коде определена ссылка на **родительский интерфейс `Statement statement`**, в которо НЕТ методов `setХхх`, см. [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).  Следует изменить тип ссылки на `PreparedStatement`, чтобы получить доступ к нужным методам интерфейса-потомка.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос был задан незадолго до этого: [Не видно публичный метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555392/)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, можете поставить зелёную галочку

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ошибка неверного синтаксиса SQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1518955/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0-sql)

Answer (score 0):

В "родительском" интерфейсе [`java.sql.Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) отсутствуют методы для установки значений параметров SQL-запросов `setString`, `setInt` и пр.

Чтобы получить доступ к методам интерфейса-"потомка" [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), используйте *правильный* тип ссылки при её определении (не забывайте о `try-with-resources`):

```java
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    pstmt.setString(1, "foo"); // метод PreparedStatement
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```